# Android Hilt DI - error: package {ApplicationClassName}_HiltComponents does not exist

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am using the new Hilt library for Dependency Injection version 2.28-alpha. I have followed the Hilt documentation and annotated the Application class with the `@HiltAndroidApp` annotation. But when I am trying to build my project, its throwing a huge list of errors all similar to:

```
error: package {ApplicationClassName}_HiltComponents does not exist

public final class Dagger{ApplicationClassName}_HiltComponents_ApplicationC extends 
{ApplicationClassName}_HiltComponents.ApplicationC {
```

I have searched for it but since its a new library, there is not much QnA available for it. Why is it throwing that error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: did you add the application class to your manifest file ?

Comment: Can you show your module and application class code ?

Comment: @takieddine yes i already had my class added to the manifest. I don't know but rebuilding the project worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: same problem. does anybody have any solution other than rebuilding because that didn't help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `Build -> Rebuild Project` worked for me.

If someone else has the same problem and rebuilding the project doesn't work, feel free to comment your problem. If someone knows why it happens, please enlighten us with your answer.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this did the trick. I guess the issue was something that was left in cache and rebuilding the project just got rid of it...

Comment: @Seven Yep. It happens quiet some times. Just ````Rebuild```` the project before doing anything else.

Comment: rebuilding the project is not helping me :/

Comment: Hi @Udit... can you elaborate your problem? Have you tried invalidating cache as well? What's happening on your end?

Comment: This seems to a bug of Hilt itself.
In my case, the renaming module class resolved this.

Answer (score 11):

For me the issue was that the `.kt` file I was in was missing its `package` block at the top.

After adding `package <my app package>` and then clean/rebuild the problem resolved itself.

Comment: Thank you friend! I wasted an hour and searched all over the place for an answer until I found this!

Answer (score 2):

For me none of the above worked. What fixed the issue was updating build tools and gradle wrapper to most recent versions.

**Gradle wrapper** from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

And **Build tools** from

```
   buildToolsVersion '29.0.1'
```

to

```
   buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, i had a similar error because the Hilt gradle plugin was defined with different version than Hilt dependency.

```
classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1")
```

And Hilt dependency was:

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.40")
```

Using `2.40` for both fixed it.

Comment: In my case I missed to update com.google.dagger:hilt-android version but I updated everywhere else.